passing data between activities in kotlin
Why am I not passing the value from editText from the second activity to the textview of the first activity?
MainActivity*

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val m_message = intent.getStringExtra("key")
        val messageText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView) as TextView
        messageText.text = m_message

    }

    fun goSecondActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

  

SecondActivity*

class SecondActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity)
        val mbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        val info: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextText)

        mbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("key", info.text)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

constants are passed without problems, but the value with EditText does not work

You must convert the EditText value to a string before passing it in the intent.
class SecondActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

    val mbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
    val info: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextText)

    mbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("key", info.text.toString())  // Convert to string here
        startActivity(intent)
    }
  }
}

The string will be passed correctly by using info.text.toString().

It's actually passed correctly, but retrieved incorrectly. He must use intent.getCharSequenceExtra("key") to retrieve it.

Yes, that's correct, we can proceed either way.

info.text value that you passed is an Editable, one of CharSequence implementation.
Your intent.putExtra("key", info.text) actually calls
Intent putExtra(String name, CharSequence value)
not
Intent putExtra(String name, String value).
With that, you must retrieve its value with intent.getCharSequenceExtra("key").
